# How to make slime block not bouncy?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is the way to make slime block become not bouncy while remaining all his original properities, how to make slime block not bouncy?

Comment: There is no such command. You would need to basically re-program a lot of Minecraft physics. Why do you need to use slime blocks at all?

Comment: I just want to know

Comment: Switch the skin of another block?

Comment: @MaxChan Well, then the answer is that it is insanely complicated and a major programming project. I asked because you might not need to use slime blocks at all, depending on what you're reallly trying to do. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Mine is a XY problem? Hard to spot it

Comment: I agree it's not an XY problem but Fabian does have a point. This would take a lot of programming.

Comment: I don't mind, I know how to program

Answer (score 1):

**You can easily do that with falling block and barrier block:**

`/summon falling_block "cordinates of slime block" {BlockState:{Name:slime_block},NoGravity:1b,Time:-999999999}`

**Before executing the command, place a barrier block at the coordinates.**

Comment: if slimeblock texture will vanish delete some time  like -999999

Answer (score -1):

Have a repeat command block with this:

```
/tp @a[x=23,y=42,z=14] 23 42 14
```

Note: the coordinates `23,42,14` are just placeholders for the coordinates representing one block above the slime block.

Comment: How can this help?

Comment: If an entity is in that coordinate, they get teleported to that same coordinate. Thus, eliminating the bounce, by the looks of the command.

Comment: No, this does not work. `x`, `y` and `z` only shift the execution position, you would still need a range. And then you get all kinds of other problems and weird glitchiness.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on what you want to use said slimeblock for.

If you as a player don't want to bounce when you fall on it, just hold shift.

But if you don't want **any** entity to bounce on the block, you either have to do loads of programming like Fabian Röling mentioned or alternatively, you can just wait for the next update where the Honey Block comes out. 
The Honey Blocks have the exact same properties of blocks sticking to it but it doesn't make entities bounce.